# Find a closed path so that the number of zeroes is equal to the winding number

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

Let $D= \{ z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$ and $T= \{ z\in \mathbb{C} : |z|=1\}$.

Let $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ be analytic on an open set $\Omega \supset D \cup T$, and suppose that $f(z)\ne0$, for all $z\in T$. Let $N_D(f)$ be the number of zeroes of $f$ in $D$, counted with multiplicities. Indicate a closed path $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ for which $N_D(f)$ is equal to the winding number of $\gamma$ around $0$.

I know that the winding number is $n(f,\gamma) = \int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$.

Also, the questions wants $N_D(f)$  equal to the winding number of $\gamma$ around $0$. So I'm suspecting that we will need Rouche's theorem?

But I'm not sure how to continue.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: hint: work backwards and try to apply the Argument Principle.

Comment: So by the Argument Principle, we want to find a closed path $\gamma$ does not contain any poles. Is that it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sort of.  How can you use the Argument Principle to count zeros in the disc?  What does that have to do with your problem?

Comment: We have winding number= $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz  $ = number of zeros - number of poles. Since we want the the number of zeros equal to the winding number. We must have the number of poles equal to zero in $\gamma$. Is this right?

Comment: The function is analytic in your disc.  Why do you mention poles?

Comment: So basically we already have the winding number equal to the number of zeros on $\gamma$ according to the Argument Principal? What is the question asking then? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What you wrote does not make sense since you have not defined $\gamma$.  There are a lot of details that need filled in.  Please update your original post with (1) a complete statement (/definition) of the Argument Principle and (2) a complete attempt at solving the exercise.

Comment: Are they asking for the winding number of $\gamma$ or the winding number of $f\circ\gamma$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Then want us to find. a closed path $\gamma$ so that the number of zeros of $f$ in $D$ is equal to the winding number of $\gamma$ around  0

Comment: So take $f(z)=z$ and $\gamma$ to be …. ? This question seems sorta crazy to me.